# Using SelectByText (partial) with C# Selenium WebDriver bindings doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using the Selenium WebDriver Extensions in C# to select a value from a select list by a partial text value (the actual has a space in front). I can't get it to work using a partial text match. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Reproducible example:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace AutomatedTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list");
            var selectList = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("can")));
            selectList.SelectByText("Featured downloads");
            Assert.AreEqual(" Featured downloads", selectList.SelectedOption.Text);
            selectList.SelectByValue("4");
            Assert.AreEqual("Deprecated downloads", selectList.SelectedOption.Text);
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Provides error:
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate element with text: Featured downloads`

Comment: Have you tried SelectByText(" Featured downloads")? I'm pretty sure none of the bindings strip whitespace from the string.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that and it works.

Comment: But I would like to select by substring, which apparently this method supports, according to the method documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *SelectByText* method is broken, so I wrote my own extension method called *SelectBySubText* to do what it is meant to do.

```
using System.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace AutomatedTests.Extensions
{
    public static class WebElementExtensions
    {
        public static void SelectBySubText(this SelectElement me, string subText)
        {
            foreach (var option in me.Options.Where(option => option.Text.Contains(subText)))
            {
                option.Click();
                return;
            }
            me.SelectByText(subText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Alister, this is a great extension and exactly what I was looking for. However, this is my first time with Selenium extensions and I'm not sure how to call it. Should I expect to see it appear in VS like mySelect.SelectBySubText(subText)?

Comment: @bearaman yes, once you have a using statement for your class, you should just call it from the Select Element as per normal

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce the problem in a simple HTML page you should definitely submit a bug report.

Looking at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/SelectElement.cs) `SelectByText` does this first:

```
FindElements(By.XPath(".//option[normalize-space(.) = " + EscapeQuotes(text) + "]"))
```

and if it doesn't find anything, then does this:

```
string substringWithoutSpace = GetLongestSubstringWithoutSpace(text);
FindElements(By.XPath(".//option[contains(., " + EscapeQuotes(substringWithoutSpace) + ")]"))
```

So in theory it should work. You can also play around with the XPath yourself and see if you can get it to work in your case.