# Selenium SelectBySubText with Ignore Case C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I found an algorithm in C-Sharp to select an element by subtext instead of text:
[Using SelectByText (partial) with C# Selenium WebDriver bindings doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133790/using-selectbytext-partial-with-c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-bindings-doesnt-se/53207883#53207883)

However I want to improve that and select by subtext and ignore case.

I tried this way, but it didn´t work:

```
public  void SelectBySubText(SelectElement me, string subText)
{
  foreach (var option in me.Options)
  {
     string textoSistema = option.Text;
     if (textoSistema.IndexOf(subText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
     {
        option.Click();
        return;
     }
  }

  me.SelectByIndex(1);
}
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get an error? If so, post the full error message. If you didn't get an error, describe what happened with examples.

Comment: Sorry.
It means that the subText was not found at testSistema (the full text = Option).
Examples:
Text = EQUIPE INTERNET
subText I tried: Equipe / equipe/ EQUIPE / EQUIPE INTERNET / Equipe Internet

Bellow Aman B explains what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition will fail only when the subtext is at the start of the text because indexOf will return 0

you should modify your condition to be:

`if (textoSistema.IndexOf(subText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)`